# How to upload files in s3 bucket with same name

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to upload the file in s3 bucket, with same name. Below is my lambda code.

```
import json
import base64
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("event",event)
    print("context",context)
    
    s3Object = boto3.client("s3")
    
    get_file_content = event["content"]
    decode_content = base64.b64decode(get_file_content)
    
    s3_upload = s3Object.put_object(Bucket="apigwbucket001", Key="test.pdf", Body=decode_content)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda! This is apiUploadBinaryFileToS3 Lambda')
    }
```

Here in `s3_upload = s3Object.put_object(Bucket="apigwbucket001", Key="aaa", Body=decode_content)`, i am giving "test.pdf" , but when i am uploading the file again, new file is getting overwritten with same name.

I am using Postman POST method collection while invoking API gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upload files with the same name to a bucket and expect both to exist.

By default, it will overwrite the older file.

You can however use version-enabled buckets
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AddingObjectstoVersioningEnabledBuckets.html